# Samsung Galaxy Ace wont charge

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-ace

Hello  my wife has the galaxy ace gt s5830 but for some reason it wont charge either off the original charger, or blackberry charger, neither off the usb in the laptop will it charge, if i take the battery out and my mate charges it in his, put it back in the phone, the phone will work fine, its not an old phone about 3mths, but draw a blank when i get intouch with the internet company i purchased from so cant return it.
Cheers Brian

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the USB port is broken, though it should be fixable with soldering or something.  Take a look outside to see if the pins were snapped off or anything, and inside if not.